# Trouble with JButtons and 2darrys

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to make a game similar to mine sweeper. I am having trouble with the JButtons.
so im trying to add the JButtons to a 2d array aligning them in a grid equal to the row and columns then add them to a panel and add the panel to the jframe, tried calling it in another class, except its doing nothing.

```
public class Field{


private int row_value;
private int column_value;
private JButton board[][];
private JPanel panel;
private GridLayout grid_layout;

//creates the board with the buttons and adds cell to each of the buttons

public Field(){

    row_values();
    Column_values();
    int x = row_value;
    int y = column_value;
    grid_layout = new GridLayout(x, y);
    board = new JButton[x][y];
        for(int row = 0; row < board[x].length ;row++){  //stops here
            for(int col = 0; col< board[y].length;col++){
                board[row][col] = new JButton();
                board[row][col].addActionListener(new Cell());//adds action listener to cell?
                 panel.add(board[row][col]);

            }

        }

    panel.setVisible(true);
    mainframe.add(panel);
}
```

Comment: Where does `mainframe` come from?

Comment: 1. All this must be running on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT), so make sure of that. 2. Cell must implement ActionListener for this to even compile. 3. You need to call frame.pack() at some point and set it visible

Comment: No need to call `panel.setVisible(true)`, only calling `mainframe.setVisible(true)` will do.

Comment: @ PM 77-1 mainframe is the another class that extends JFrame  where i have created my frame, i was just testing to see if add it that way..

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example).